# how to find a list of users running a particular process

Tags: shell, batch-file

I have to send a msg to a plurality of users who perform a specific process:
How can I find a list of usernames, performing, for example the image "chrome.exe", and then send msg to these users.
All the activities described above, must be in a bat-file
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why *must* it be a batch file? It would be *much* easier with Microsoft's modern, preferred system scripting & administration tool, PowerShell. Homework, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments to xmcp's answer, I expanded the code a bit:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" /fo csv /nh /v') do ( 
  set line=%%x 
  set line=!line:","="@"! 
  for /f "tokens=7 delims=@" %%a in (!line!) do echo %%~a 
)
```

It replaces the field separators (`","`), without touching the comma within the numbers (in some localizations) and parses the resulting string with a different separator. Downside: it slows things down (theoretically, I don't think anyone will notice it)

Comment: Also a nice work-around! although the `@` might appear in image and/or session names, so perhaps it was a good idea to switch to a prohibited character (e. g., `?`, `|`, etc.)... alternatively, let a [standard `for` loop handle commas and quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39081459)... ;-)

Comment: @aschipfl usually, if I need a save delimiter, I tend to use 0x254

Comment: But this is code-page-dependent, and it is also allowed in process file/image/session names...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=8" %%i in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe" /fo table /nh /v') do echo %%i
```

Please be aware that the code might be buggy if the image name contains spaces, but I can't find a perfect solution in plain batch-file.

Explanation:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: spaces don't matter, if you use the approach from your comment (`/fo csv`) and adapt your `for` a little bit: `for /f "tokens=7 delims=," %%a in (' tasklist /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" /fo csv /nh /v') do echo %%~a`

Comment: @Stephan  but what about `32,500 K`?

Comment: please try; should work because of the quotes; can't verify (my system says `32.500 K`)

Comment: well, that's not working. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23078314/  i'm under windows 7 with code page 936 (zh-cn)

Comment: @Stephan, what do you mean by "because of the quotes", which quotes?

Comment: @aschipfl the result is quoted in csv format. see the [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23078314/)

Comment: @aschipfl: `tasklist /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" /fo csv 
` gives me `"Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage" 
"firefox.exe","17648","Console","1","280.504 K"`

Answer (score 0):

[xmcp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5210803)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079840) shows the perfect command to retrieve processes and the names of their owning users. However, their solution fails in case of additional white-spaces appearing within the data.

To make it more safe, use the [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) output format of the `tasklist` command, capture its output by a `for /F` loop in full lines/rows and extract the single column/cell items by a standard `for` loop:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Capture CSV-formatted output without header; `tasklist` returns these columns:
rem    `"Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage","Status","User Name","CPU Time","Window Title"`: */
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
    tasklist /FI "ImageName eq Chrome.exe" /FI "Status eq Running" /V /NH /FO CSV
') do (
    rem // Initialise column counter:
    set /A "CNT=0"
    rem /* Use standard `for` loop to enumerate columns, as this regards quoting;
    rem    note that the comma `,` is a standard delimiter in `cmd`: */
    for %%I in (%%L) do (
        rem // Store item with surrounding quotes removed:
        set "ITEM=%%~I"
        rem /* Store item with surrounding quotes preserved, needed for later
        rem    filtering out of (unquoted) message in case of no match: */
        set "TEST=%%I"
        rem // Increment column counter:
        set /A CNT+=1
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion not to lose exclamation marks:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* in case no match is found, this message appears:
        rem    `INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.`;
        rem    since this contains no quotes, the following condition fails: */
        if not "!ITEM!"=="!TEST!" (
            rem // The 7th column holds the user name:
            if !CNT! EQU 7 echo(!ITEM!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This simply echoes the name of every user that is currently running a process named `Chrome.exe`. To send messages to them, you might use the [`net send`](http://ss64.com/nt/net_send.html) command instead of `echo`.

This approach does not work in case the CSV data contains global wild-card characters `*` and `?`; such characters should not occur in image, session and names; they may appear in window titles though, but these appear after the user names in the `tasklist` output anyway.